# Vespa Tutorial – HTTP API use-case fails to activate with IllegalArgumentException

Tags: vespa

I'm currently following the Vespa tutorials, and ran into an issue with the [HTTP API use-case](http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/handler-tutorial.html). Everything works fine from the `mvn install package` to the `vespa-deploy prepare target/application.zip`.

The call to `vespa-deploy activate` returns normally, but the application then never gets available on `localhost:8080`. Looking at `/opt/vespa/logs/vespa/vespa.log` (in the VM) one finds the following stack trace:

```
Container.com.yahoo.jdisc.core.StandaloneMain   error   Unexpected: 
  exception=
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create a component with id 'com.mydomain.demo.DemoComponent'.
    Tried to load class directly, since no bundle was found for spec: sample-app-http-api-searcher. 
    If a bundle with the same name is installed, there is a either a version mismatch or the installed bundle's version contains a qualifier string.
    at com.yahoo.osgi.OsgiImpl.resolveFromClassPath(OsgiImpl.java:48)
    ...
```

This occurred using a fresh Docker image with a clean clone of the `sample-apps` git repository. Preparing and activating the basic sample as well as the other http example did work seamlessly.

I checked the sources and the xml files for obvious problems but don't have any clue about what is failing and where.

`target/application.zip` contains

```
application/components/http-api-using-searcher-1.0.1-deploy.jar
application/hosts.xml
application/searchdefinitions/basic.sd
application/services.xml
```

And the jar itself does contain a `com/mydomain/demo/DemoComponent.class` file (among other things).

<sub>Potentially related issue on the github tracker: https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/issues/3479 I'll be posting a link to this question there as well, but I still think it's worth a SO question, at least to get some action behind the `vespa` tag :)</sub>

Comment: What is the contents of target/application.zip ? It complains that it cannot initialize the component as 'since no bundle was found for spec: sample-app-http-api-searcher'

Comment: Question updated. Many thanks for the prompt replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bundle id in the application's services.xml file was wrong. Please pull the application from git and try again now. See also PR: https://github.com/vespa-engine/sample-apps/pull/18

Brief explanation: The bundle id given in the `bundle="<id>"` declaration in services.xml must match the 'Bundle-SymbolicName' in the bundle's manifest. When the bundle has been built with the Vespa bundle-plugin, the symbolic name is by default the same as the project's artifactId. Hence, in most cases you just have to verify that the bundle id matches the artifactId.

Comment: Many thanks! Wishing you guys a pleasant evening up in Norway :)